# Долгий вывод таблицы из SQL в PyQT5 QTableWidget

Tags: python, sql, pyqt5

У меня есть таблица которую я получаю из OracleSQL, данную таблицу я вывожу в своем приложении в QTableWidget, но уже при относительно небольшой таблице (22 столбца и 100 строк) отрисовка таблицы занимает 10-12 секунд. Возможно ли как то изменить мой код что бы ускорить вывод данных?

```
sql.oracle_con()
sql.cursor.execute(f"select * from prod.request where status='FAILED'")
table = sql.cursor.fetchall()
col_names = [row[0] for row in sql.cursor.description]
self.ui.MonitoringTable.setColumnCount(len(col_names))
self.ui.MonitoringTable.setRowCount(len(table))
self.ui.MonitoringTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col_names)
row_number = 0
for row in table:
   col = 0
   for item in row:
      cellinfo = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
      cellinfo.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
      self.ui.MonitoringTable.setItem(row_number, col, cellinfo)
      col += 1
   row_number += 1
sql.conn.close()
```

Я пробывал заменить QTableWidget на QTableView, но скорость отрисовки совсем не изменилась.

Comment: если QTableView ничего не дает, то либо ваша таблица вычисляемая и долго работает сам запрос, либо вы что-то не так делаете используя tableview

Comment: При использовании QTableView я создавал модель, привязывал ее к tableview и наполнял примерно таким же цилом как наполняю QTableWidget.

Я делал временные метки при выполнении этой функции, основное время занимает цикл запыления ячеек\модели. Мы можем убрать SQL запрос из этой функции и представить что у нас просто готовая data = [] с таким же объёмом данных, но отрисовка все равно занимает тоже время.

Comment: чем не угодил QSqlTableModel?

Comment: Я только начал изучать QT и мои познания питона не очень обширны. Но если я правильно понял, для использования QSqlTableModel необходимо подключится к бд через QSqlQuery, а оно не умеет работать с OracleSQL, хотя я могу ошибаться.

Comment: нет. QSqlQuery - прямые запросы к БД. Необходимо только соединение QSqlDatabase с использованием драйвера QOCI (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qoci)